# Drupal Display Suite Nested Layouts

Tags: drupal

A supposed competitive advantage of Drupal's Display Suite over the Panels module is the ability to have nested layouts. Is there any supporting documentation, especially a complete example?

Answer (score 0):

You could read the documentation about both the modules given.That might lead you in the right direction.Hope this tutorial link might help you with the necessary details.

**Display Suite**

https://drupal.org/node/644662

**Panels**

https://drupal.org/node/496278

**COMPARING PANELS AND DISPLAY SUITE SIDE-BY-SIDE**

http://buildamodule.com/video/advanced-site-building-in-drupal-7-how-to-use-panels-for-positioning-content-comparing-panels-and-display-suite-side-by-side#viewing

Comment: I was asking because I have seen this mentioned but not documented in my previous study of the Display Suite page you mention. I saw this in a screencast: 
"Double nesting: In DS, you can put your fields in one of the 5 regions, but inside those regions, you can also group them together in fieldgroups", which would be very big news if it were true.